# How to dynamically get all images from shared folder using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, .net

I am bit stuck with the problem, i have created a document library in sharepoint directory [path](https://synergyitpk.sharepoint.com/EasyBrand365/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=19b2bd8130cdf4912974bf3e782987e5d&authkey=AXKtqqDFs5Qp1FwagiDYMhc) containing images.

I am trying to get all the images from [this](https://synergyitpk.sharepoint.com/EasyBrand365/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=19b2bd8130cdf4912974bf3e782987e5d&authkey=AXKtqqDFs5Qp1FwagiDYMhc) folder with their name and URL.

But couldn't find any solution using CSOM.

If anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

The code is quite simple, check this example

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("Your site name"))
        {
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List docList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document library Name");
            ctx.Load(docList);
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            //This will get all items in folders
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
            ListItemCollection listCol = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            ctx.Load(listCol);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in listCol)
            {
                //item["FileDirRef"] //Title
                //item["FileLeafRef"] //url
            }
        }
```